# Docker build: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http on X.X.X.X:53: no such host

Tags: docker, ubuntu

When I tried to build docker image:

```bash
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f "tools/docker/Dockerfile" -t hello:latest --target hello "."
```

I got this error from `FROM ubuntu:impish AS baseimg`:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

I have tried to set nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` and restart docker. It shows same error with the `127.0.0.1` changing to the DNS IP I just set. Actually, `nslookup auth.docker.io` works fine with any DNS server. And `docker pull` works fine too. The problem only shows up when I try to build images.

I also have tried to `docker logout; docker login`, turn off or turn on the proxy. They all can't solve the problem.

Some info:

- System: Ubuntu 22.04
- docker version: Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a
- `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.4
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.17.3
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 23.0.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc version: v1.1.5-0-gf19387a
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.19.0-41-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 12
 Total Memory: 31.15GiB
 Name: Ubuntu-Inspiron-5680
 ID: 56fe649e-4761-4b6d-a258-828187c1f242
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: fals
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

just add (before trying to pull anything from the internet) in your Dockerfile:

```
COPY /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

or if you do not want to rely on the /etc/resolv.conf from your host, you can hardcode `nameserver`s in the building image:

```
RUN echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```